# simple jsf application in myeclipse using jBoss

Tags: java, interface

I want to run simple application of jsf but after configuring jBoss in my application I got the following error.

14:58:38,328 ERROR [[/web3demo]] Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: CONFIGURATION FAILED! 
  Source Document: jndi:/localhost/web3demo/WEB-INF/faces-config.xml
  Cause: Class 'com.icesoft.faces.facelets.D2DFaceletViewHandler' is missing a runtime dependency: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/impl/ResourceResolver

DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "vfsfile:/E:/ctn%20sodtware/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/2832010.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.xml.sax.SAXException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '2832010' is not a valid value for 'NCName'. @ vfsfile:/E:/ctn%20sodtware/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/2832010.war/WEB-INF/web.xml[5,16]
  Deployment "vfsfile:/E:/ctn%20sodtware/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/web3demo.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/E:/ctn sodtware/jboss-5.0.1.GA/server/default/deploy/web3demo.war/ deployment failed

This is simple application where I simply run default index file without creating any other jsf file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the facelets jar as evident from the missing class error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/facelets/impl/ResourceResolver